# How to make text with image align center vertically in table

Tags: html, css

I want to center the text vertically but no idea how, you can see what I'm trying to achieve in fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/jTW4d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
td { vertical-align: middle }
img { vertical-align: middle }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jTW4d/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
td img, td span{
    display:inline-block;
    .display:inline;
    .zoom:1;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

here is an update : http://jsfiddle.net/jTW4d/4/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `.` instead of the more common `*`?

Comment: it is just as an option, this way is going to work even using block elements like <div>, where you cannot use "td { vertical-align: middle }".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jTW4d/9/ - I used line-height css property to fix this.